# Inheriting SQL Server table permission

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have a question about permission on the SQL server table. We have two SQL servers (sql-1, sql-2). The actual tables are on the sql-2, the synonyms to the actual tables are on sql-1 and the permission are set on sql-2.

I was not aware of this setup initially, so I took what I thought was a table on sql-1 at the time and did a INSERT into new table on sql-1, thinking I would inherit all the permissions.  It did not.  My question is when I was doing the Insert, even though the original table resides in sql-2, but when the insert is run on sql-1, would it not take the permission on sql-2 based on the synonym on sql-1 and apply it on the new table on sql-1?

The solution to my problem was to create the new table on sql-2, create the synonym on sql-1 pointing to sql-2 for the table, then set up the permission on sql-1 in the synonym itself on the new table in sql-2.

Comment: If you have a cross server query, no permission inheritance can ever occur.

Comment: Larnu, thanks for your comment.  The permission on the original synonym was on sql-1 so when I did the select into [newtable] from synonym on sql-1, the permission would not be inherited on the [newtable] that's also on sql-1?  I am asking this because, yes while the actual source table is on sql-2, the permission is on sql-1 on the synonym.  Thanks for your thought.

Comment: there seems to be a linked server be setup on sql-1 right? In this case there is defined, which credentials are used when accessing the data via it. So not your login is used but the one which was defined in the linked server

Comment: Using SELECT INTO does not inherit permissions - in fact, it cannot inherit permissions because permissions are not created on a table.  Permissions are created on the user or role.

Comment: @Larnu That is not strictly true: Windows Authentication can pass through, although obviously it depends on what permissions are given to that login on the other server

Comment: That isn't permission inheritence though, @Charlieface , that's authentication pass through or Kerboros. I read the question as more than they as expecting that the `USER`/`LOGIN` will have permission to access the objects on the other server due to the permission chaining, like when you have 2 objects in the same database with the same owner.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your thoughts and comments, it helped me a lot to get a better understanding.  Much appreciated.